# Javascript drag node from tree and drop to box

Tags: javascript, tree

I am searching for a js script that will create a draggable tree. The drop of the node should be placed in a seperate box or list. Where can I find a similar piece of code in order to use it in my site?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's many of this around the web but look at these:

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-6

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-folder-tree/drag-drop-folder-tree.html

http://www.jstree.com/demo